# How to determine button id in another view depending on a different view Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm making an app where some activities are listed in a table called `Fakultety` (polish language, sorry), and participants on in another table called `Uczestnicy`.
I have a submit form where you can submit yourself to an activity, but I'm stuck on passing values to a DB. Firstly, I don't know how to tell to the database on which activity you want to be assigned to (I tried to change the submit button id to an activity id and then passing it into a database but don't know how to do this `id: "#{@fakultet.id}"` not working) and later I want to count how many people are assigned to field `participants` in a database `Fakultety`, but I don't want to pass all the data, just ID of the users from table called `Uczestnicy`. How to do it? I mean just to pass the ids to another table, and how to tell the database on which activity I want to be assigned to?

This is my form view:

```
<h1>Zapisujesz sie na fakultet</h1>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@participant, url: zapisy_path) do |f| %>
      <p>Imię:</p>
      <%= f.text_field :firstName, class: 'form-control' %>

      <p>Nazwisko:</p>
      <%= f.text_field :lastName, class: 'form-control' %>
      <p>Grupa:</p>
      <%= f.text_field :group, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Zapisz się", class: "btn btn-primary" id: "#{@fakultet.id}"%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody understand me and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Rails provides [form collection helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) that make it really easy to assign associations:

```
# I'm going to just do this in english
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:participant_ids, Partipicant.all, :id, :name, prompt: true, multiple: :new) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Then whitelist the attribute as an array:

```
params.require(:activity).permit(:foo, :bar, participants_ids: [])
```

Thats all you actually need to assign childen to  to a parent resource. This is done as a part of the normal create/update actions of the parent resource.

You don't actually need the form for the child records unless you actually want to be creating the record. In that case you can setup a [nested resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) or if you want to create/edit multiple nested records at the same time as the parent record you can use [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Answer (score -1):

First you should rename your models and tables, to English, it's a really bad pattern to use your language, in English it is easier to understand by other devs.
According to the problem, probably what you are looking for is `hidden_field`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :fakultet_id, :value => @fakultet.id %>
```

and if you want to query `Fakultety` that have user assigned, you can select `Fakultety` where `participant_id` is not `nil`

```
Fakultety.where.not(participant_id: nil)
```

Comment: Passing ids in hidden fields is usually just a really bad idea done by people who don't have a clue what they are doing. I don't see how it would actually solve the problem here.